# get path from where QGIS is loading the plugin dll

Tags: qgis-plugins, c++

In my QGIS plugin I want to get the path of my plugin. As yet I done this so:

```
QDir appDir=QDir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
appDir.cdUp();
QString sPluginFile=appDir.path()+"/apps/qgis/plugins/plugin.dll";
```

Since QGIS LTR sometimes the plugin.dll is located at

> /apps/qgis-ltr/plugins/plugin.dll

so my code above is not working anymore. Has anobody an idea how to get the path from where QGIS my plugin has loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After found the class `QgsPluginRegistry` it seems to be very easy to get the complete path of my dll:

```
    #include "qgspluginregistry.h"
    ...
    QgsPluginRegistry *pRegistry = QgsPluginRegistry::instance();
    QString library = pRegistry->library( "name_of_my_plugin" );
```

But this class is not offered to the [API](http://qgis.org/api/2.14/), had to search it in the sources of QGIS!